# multiple foreach loops inside while loop

Tags: c#

is it possible to include multiple "foreach" statements inside any of the looping constructs like while or for ... i want to open the .wav files from two different directories simultaneously so that i can compare files from both.
here is what i am trying to so but it is certainly wrong.. any help in this regard is appreciated.

```
string[] fileEntries1 = Directory.GetFiles(folder1, "*.wav");
string[] fileEntries2 = Directory.GetFiles(folder11, "*.wav");
while ( foreach(string fileName1 in fileEntries1) && foreach(string fileName2 in fileEntries2))
```

Comment: What's that extra while loop for? What about nested for each loops?

Comment: what if both lists are different by length?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this since you only need to validate same file names:

```
IEnumerable<string> fileEntries1 = Directory.GetFiles(folder1, "*.wav").Select(x => Path.GetFileName(x));
IEnumerable<string> fileEntries2 = Directory.GetFiles(folder2, "*.wav").Select(x => Path.GetFileName(x));

IEnumerable<string> filesToIterate = (fileEntries1.Count() > fileEntries2.Count()) ? fileEntries1 : fileEntries2;
IEnumerable<string> filesToValidate = (fileEntries1.Count() < fileEntries2.Count()) ? fileEntries1 : fileEntries2;

// Iterate the bigger collection
foreach (string fileName in filesToIterate)
{
    // Find the files in smaller collection
    if (filesToValidate.Contains(fileName))
    {
        // Get actual file and compare
    }
    else
    {
        // File does not exist in another list. Handle appropriately
    }
}
```

.Net 2.0 based solution:

```
List<string> fileEntries1 = new List<string>(Directory.GetFiles(folder1, "*.wav"));

List<string> fileEntries2 = new List<string>(Directory.GetFiles(folder2, "*.wav"));

List<string> filesToIterate = (fileEntries1.Count > fileEntries2.Count) ? fileEntries1 : fileEntries2;
filesToValidate = (fileEntries1.Count < fileEntries2.Count) ? fileEntries1 : fileEntries2;

string iteratorFileName;
string validatorFilePath;

// Iterate the bigger collection
foreach (string fileName in filesToIterate)
{
    iteratorFileName = Path.GetFileName(fileName);

    // Find the files in smaller collection
    if ((validatorFilePath = FindFile(iteratorFileName)) != null)
    {
        // Compare fileName and validatorFilePath files here
    }
    else
    {
        // File does not exist in another list. Handle appropriately
    }
}
```

FindFile method:

```
static List<string> filesToValidate;

private static string FindFile(string fileToFind)
{
    string returnValue = null;

    foreach (string filePath in filesToValidate)
    {
        if (string.Compare(Path.GetFileName(filePath), fileToFind, true) == 0)
        {
            // Found the file
            returnValue = filePath;
            break;
        }
    }

    if (returnValue != null)
    {
        // File was found in smaller list. Remove this file from the list since we do not need to look for it again
        filesToValidate.Remove(returnValue);    
    }

    return returnValue;    
}
```

You may or may not choose to make fields and methods static based on your needs.

Comment: thanks a ton.. this code is working fine.. but i am facing a small issue regarding this.. this code makes use of namespace system.Linq which is not supported by .Net 2.0 (which is the requirement) i even tried writing a config file for the same... still it is not working.. is there a solution to this..?

Comment: @user3582072 Added .Net 2.0 based solution. Not the most elegant way to do this but I believe this will work.

Answer (score 2):

Gramatically speaking no. This is because a `foreach` construct is a *statement* whereas the tests in a `while` statement must be *expressions*.

Your best bet is to nest the `foreach` blocks:

```
foreach(string fileName1 in fileEntries1)
{
    foreach(string fileName2 in fileEntries2)
```

Answer (score 1):

I like this kind of statements in one line. So even though most of the answers here are correct, I give you this.

```
string[] fileEntries1 = Directory.GetFiles(folder1, "*.wav");
string[] fileEntries2 = Directory.GetFiles(folder11, "*.wav");

foreach( var fileExistsInBoth in fileEntries1.Where(fe1 => fileEntries2.Contains(fe1) )
{
    /// here you will have the records which exists in both of the lists
}
```

Comment: the "where" and "contains" keywords are present in the namespace of systems.arguments.nullexceptions.. which is not supported by .net2.0 i think . can u provide an alternative that works within the boundary of .Net2.0 .. thank you..:)

Comment: I don't think I can, other than the accepted answer. My answer will require .net 3.5 at least. Even if there are workarounds and hacks to include `LINQ` in .net 2.0 applications I wouldn't try to do so.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to iterate all pairs of files in both paths respectively, you can do it as follows.

```
string[] fileEntries1 = Directory.GetFiles(folder1, "*.wav");
string[] fileEntries2 = Directory.GetFiles(folder11, "*.wav");

foreach(string fileName1 in fileEntries1)
{
    foreach(string fileName2 in fileEntries2)
    {
        // to the actual comparison
    }
}
```

Comment: i don't want to loop through all the possible pairs .. i just want to compare 1.wav from folder1 to 1.wav of folder11 .. is there a way to do it..

Comment: What should be the result if both folders contain files of different names, e.g. `folder1` contains a file which is not contained in `folder11`?

Answer (score 0):

This is what I would suggest, using linq

```
using System.Linq;

var fileEntries1 = Directory.GetFiles(folder1, "*.wav");
var fileEntries2 = Directory.GetFiles(folder11, "*.wav");
foreach (var entry1 in fileEntries1)
{
    var entries = fileEntries2.Where(x => Equals(entry1, x));
    if (entries.Any())
    {
        //We have matches
        //entries is a list of matches in fileentries2 for entry1
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to enable both collections "in parallel", then use their iterators like this:

```
var fileEntriesIterator1 = Directory.EnumerateFiles(folder1, "*.wav").GetEnumerator();
var fileEntriesIterator2 = Directory.EnumerateFiles(folder11, "*.wav").GetEnumerator();

while(fileEntriesIterator1.MoveNext() && fileEntriesIterator2.MoveNext())
{
    var file1 = fileEntriesIterator1.Current;
    var file2 = fileEntriesIterator2.Current;
}
```

If one collection is shorter than the other, this loop will end when the shorter collection has no more elements.